# Which is the illegal instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, 64-bit, nasm

Well, I copied this code exactly from page 17 of 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_tutorial.pdf
but when I compiled it with NASM (on windows even though in the pdf they use linux)
using the command `nasm -f elf test.asm -o test.com`, and run it it spits this out at me:

```
16 bit MS-DOS Subsystem

dir The NTVDM CPU has encountered an illegal instruction.
CS:0000 IP:0077 OP:fo 37 05 0a 02 Choose 'Close' to terminate the application.
```

where `dir` is the location from which I compiled and ran the program (nasm directory). I hope I don't make a total tit out of myself for this, but it really is puzzling me.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

```
int 0x80 ;call kernel
```

You're on windows -- dos even. The address you're using in this instruction (`0x80`) is Linux/Unix specific.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_(x86_instruction)

Comment: On DOS, in fact. Its interrupt-based API is extensively documented; just find one that more or less matches whatever syscall you were trying to do.